# How to take input from Touch screen and save into Bitmap format?

Tags: java, android

I want to take Signature input from device touch screen and save that drawable into Bitmap so that later i can upload that bitmap into Server.
Can anyone provide the code coz its really urgent.

Thanks in advance to every reader and helper.

Comment: *provide the code coz its really urgent.* SO is not Spoon Feeding Site,If its really urgent hire any developer do your job.

Answer (score 1):

You should probably used TouchPaint of FingerPaint app from APIDemos. Go through [this link](http://blahti.wordpress.com/2010/11/18/how-to-save-jpeg-files-in-the-android-emulator/) as well

Answer (score 1):

try with SVG format. you need to store all the touch point x,y in an array ,convert it to svg . for help go through w3school.

Comment: Can u please provide me little coding detail.